# Drawing Transparent image over NSImage

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage

I'm trying to draw a logo in an image.This works fine using the following code

```
logo!.draw(in:logoRect)
```

But there is no transparency option,so i use another parameter.But this does not produce any output.

```
logo?.draw(in: mainimage, from: logoRect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.sourceOver, fraction: 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> logo!.draw(in:logoRect)

if above works then use the following

```
logo!.draw(in:logoRect, from: .zero, operation: .sourceOver, fraction: 0.5))
```